# Import interface from @types/chrome not working

Tags: typescript, interface

In my angular project I'm trying to type the following code

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(
    (changes: StorageChange, namespace: string) => { ... }
);
```

The problem is with the interface `StorageChange`, it comes from `@types/chrome`

[image]

Whatever I do, my IDE (vscode) and `tsc` complain about it. I've tried to add "chrome" to tsconfig.json

```
...
types: [ "chrome" ],
...
```

Didn't work. Tried to add import statements

```
///<reference types="chrome"/>
```

or

```
import { StorageChange } from '@types/chrome';
```

No success, Any suggestions how I can fix this?